# Подсчет количества вызовов метода на этапе компиляции

Tags: c++, c++14, матрицы

Стоит задача реализовать разреженную N-мерную матрицу.

Двумерную получилось сделать:
https://github.com/avovana/homework_06/blob/master/src/main.cpp

Для неё такой API:

```
SparseMatrix < int, 0 > matrix; // int - тип значений, 0 - дефолтное значение

for(int i = 0, j = 0; i <= 9; ++i, ++j)
{
    matrix[i][j] = i;
    matrix[9 - i][j] = 9 - i;
}

(matrix[2][8] = 99) = 88;
assert(matrix[2][8] == 88);
std::cout << "(matrix[2][8] = 99) = 88;" << '\n';
std::cout << "matrix[2][8]: " << matrix[2][8] << '\n';
std::cout << "Matrix size = " << matrix.size() << '\n';
```

Для этого при первом вызове `operator[]` выдается объект-прослойка, у которой можно вызвать `operator[]`, что даст объект, имеющий доступ к дате - можно и выводить значение, и присваивать.

Но, когда матрица N мерная(4, к примеру), то нужен такой API:

```
SparseMatrix < int, 0, 4 > matrix;
matrix[0][1][5][4] = 3;
```

Т.е. объект-прослойка должен последовательно вызваться несколько раз перед тем, как будет вызван объект(печатая `[4]` в данном случае), имеющий доступ к дате.

Вот код:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/KPTCkVjOCJN08sj4

По идее, количество вызовов `operator[]` должно быть однозначно связано с размерностью.
Нужно отдать проверку на сторону компилятора.

К примеру, инстанцируя новую матрицу с размерностью 4 нужно как-то следить, что было именно 3 вызова `оператора[]` у объекта прослойки - каждый раз возвращая себя же и накапливая информацию о введенных значениях.

Затем должен следовать, скорее-всего, вызов специализированного `оператора[]` у объекта прослойки, который бы вернул уже объект, имеющей доступ к данным.

Возможно ли воспользоваться `constexpr` или еще чем-нибудь, чтобы достичь желаемого результата(доступен С++14)?

P.S. Можно бы сделать что-то в духе:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34011555/compile-time-limit-on-number-of-function-calls-in-c/34011950#34011950

Но какая-то сложная там реализация. Её минус, что каждый раз создается новый объект - а это накладные расходы.

Comment: Что тогда означает "на этапе компиляции" в заголовке вопроса?

Comment: @AnT, это значит в момент компилирования программы. Или вопрос в другом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ — это рекурсивно создавать классы прослойки меньшей размерности при каждом вызове оператора. Дойдя до нужной глубины, просто возвращаем данные.

Это может выглядеть как-то так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<size_t D>
class Proxy
{
public:
    Proxy<D - 1> operator[](size_t) const
    {
        return Proxy<D - 1>{};
    }
};

template<>
class Proxy<1>
{
public:
    size_t operator[](size_t) const
    {
        return 77;
    }
};

template<size_t D>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Proxy<D> operator[](size_t) const
    {
        return Proxy<D>{};
    }
};

int main()
{
    const Matrix<4> mat{};
    cout << mat[0][1][2][3][4];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за простой и супер понятный пример!